# How can i pass parameters to a web page using oracle forms?

Tags: oracle, forms

I'm trying to send parameters to a web site, with no success.
Can anyone please show me a way of how to do it?
an example of one way of doing it in ASP for instance is like that:

```
Response.Write(http://ads.hevre.co.il/External_Leads_insert_fullDetails.asp?afid=2512&Firstname="AAA"&Exfield1="BBB"&"&phone="321321321"&Exfield2="DDD"&zip="32121")
```

any suggestions of how to implement it in oracle forms??

thanks in advance,
Alon Kogan.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a web page and get the response using [UTL_HTTP](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_http.htm#CHDIAFFA), which is available in Oracle 9i, 10g and 11g. I recommend you create a PL/SQL package on the database and call it from your form.

> "The `UTL_HTTP` package makes
>   Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP)
>   callouts from SQL and PL/SQL. You can
>   use it to access data on the Internet
>   over HTTP."